# How to compile Java code with formal parameters information (-parameters compiler arg) in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, compilation

As per this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html), I should use the **-parameters** option to tell the Java compiler to store formal parameter names in a particular .class file.

With Maven, the compiler can be instructed to do so as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArgument>-parameters</compilerArgument>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

How can I do that in Intellij IDEA, so that it is used by default?

Please note, **-parameters** is not VM option.

Comment: Did you do any research before posting?

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of IntelliJ pick up this option automatically when importing a Maven project with a pom.xml file configured as you posted. So no manual configuration of IntelliJ is required.

Note that a rebuild (Menu → *Build* → *Rebuild Project*) may be required after updating the pom.xml file.

Answer (score -1):

You have to open settings, locate java compiler options and add '-parameters' to it.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to do so, but it wasn't being picked up by Jackson. Now it is. Thanks